# Control RateOfFire (Java GameDev)

Tags: java

I' m currently writing a simple 2D game in java from scratch (for learning purposes)

I want to control the rate at which a player can shoot. The method done there works, but it could be improved. The method is getting called if the user presses/holds the left mouse button. It works when the user is holding the button pressed, but when he/she releases the mouse button, waits (more then the rateOfFire time) and tries to shoot it may or may not work, because the roftC value isn' t getting updated when the player doesn' t shoot.
I tried then to put it into my `update()` method (which gets called 60 times a second). The problem still exists. I really have no idea how to solve this. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Used to control the rate of fire
 */
private int roftC = 0;
/**
 * Shoot a Projectile
 */
protected void shoot(int x, int y, double dir) {
        Projectile p = new Bomb(x, y, dir);
        if (roftC % p.getRateOfFire() == 0) {
            level.addProjectile(p);
        }
        if (roftC > 6000) {
            roftC = 0;
        }
        roftC++; // Whether it is here or down there doesn' t make a diffrence
}


 /**
  * 
  */
  @Override
  public void update() {
      // roftC++;
    }
```

Comment: What GUI/game library? How is your game loop set up?

Comment: I think this doesn' t really matter for this question. But to answer your question: It' s from scratch. No libs and my own 2D graphics engine (based on a Canvas).

Comment: Why don't you introduce a boolean variable that holds the player's state i.e. if he is shooting or not, depending on the mouse press. If I got it right, it seems that the rate of fire needs to be controlled only when the player is shooting right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to introduce a minimum delay between shots. Something like this:

```
static final long MINIMUM_DELAY = 1000/30; // So we can have 30 shots per second
long lastShotTimestamp;

protected void shoot(int x, int y, double dir) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (now - lastShotTimestamp > MINIMUM_DELAY) {
        level.addProjectile(new Bomb(x, y, dir));
        lastShotTimestamp = now;
    }
}
```

Such an approach is actually close to the physics - a gun needs some time to reload between consecutive shots.

Comment: Thanks. The idea too work with timestamps is awesome. I' ve changed the implementation a bit (the getFireRate() methods returns the DELAY), but the idea is the same. Awesome.